# CoreBluetooth - didDiscoverPeripheral in background mode not called without LightBlue

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to scan for BLE device in the background but my didDiscoverPeripheral method is not getting called. I've been waiting for 5 minutes and nothing happened but when I open other bluetooth app like "LightBlue" my didDiscoverPeripheral gets called immediately. This happens everytime. How can I make this work without running LightBlue?

Here's my code for scanning:
`central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [cbuuid], options: nil)`

Project has correct background settings, because didDiscoverPeripheral is working in background after launching LightBlue.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out where the problem was.

The bluetooth device has two types of advertisement, one is without service uuid. In background iOS skips advertisements without service uuid. I've changed all advertisements packets inside device to have services uuid and everything is working now.